# VueJS SPA dynamic baseURL for axios

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, vue-cli, laravel-sanctum

I've searched and searched and can't seem to find a pattern for this. I'd consider myself an intermediate Vue dev, however, the backend is my strong suit. I'm working on an app that will be white-labeled by resellers. While it's possible to have multiple builds, avoiding that would be ideal.  The setup is a stand-alone vue-cli SPA connecting to a Laravel api backend and using the Sanctum auth package. So I need calls to the same domain. The issue: resellers will be on their own domain. The ask: Is there a pattern/solution for dynamically loading configs (mainly baseURL) for different domains (other items would by theme/stylesheet). Currently I have a few typical entries:

i.e. `axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL`

Basically, based on the domain the site is being served on, I'd like a dynamic/runtime config. I feel like this has been solved, but I can't seem to use the right search terms for some direction, so anything is helpful. I've tried a few things:

1) Parsing in js, but can't seem to get it to run early enough in the process to take effect? It seems to work, but I can't get it to "click"

2) Hit a public API endpoint with the current domain and get the config. Again, can implement, but can't seem to get it to inject into the Vue side correctly?

Any resources, pattern references or general guidance would be much appreciative to avoid maintaining multiple builds merely for a few variables. That said, I don't think there's much overhead in any of this, but also open to telling my I'm wrong and need multiple builds.

#### End Result

url visited is `https://mydomaincom`

then `baseURL = https://api.mydomiancom`

url visited `https://resellerdomaincom`

then `baseURL=https://api.resellerdomaincom`

Answer (score 0):

Honestly how the question is put it's not really clear to me. Although my usual pattern is to:

Create an axios instance like so:

```
export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  // ...configs
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_URL_YOU_WOULD_LIKE_TO_HIT
})
```

and then whenever I make a request to some api, I would use this instance.

EDIT: According to your edit, you can either release the client to each customer, and have a .env file for each and every of them, or you can have a gateway system, where the client axios end point is always the same, hitting always the same server, and then from there the server decides what to ping, based on your own logic

Comment: Correct, but the question is how to make `process.env.VUE_APP_URL_YOU_WOULD_LIKE_TO_HIT` variable at runtime. Meaning if the url visited is https://mydomaincom then the baseURL = https://api.mydomiancom and if the url is https://resellerdomaincom then the baseURL=https://api.resellerdomaincom - I'll edit the question with that clarity

Comment: It cannot be at runtime. the process.env.VUE_APP_etc is a string replacement which happens in build time. So, if you have 10 sites, you can have 10 .env files with 10 different endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a common pattern to solve your problem - I haven't found anything on the net.

The best software design solution could be the following:

- have a single back-end
- distribute only the client to your customers/resellers

Obviously the back end could see the domain of the application from which the request comes and manage the logic accordingly.

Good luck with your project.